# Divi Theme Builder Keeps Loading

Tags: php, wordpress, divi

The Divi theme builder keeps loading when enabled in any pages. I updated the WordPress, Divi and PHP although the problem persists. Can anyone help me solve the issue.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How to Ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the safe mode from dashboard > Divi > Support option.
Enable Safe Mode, sometimes 3rd party plugins or server causes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have purchased the Divi theme, you should be able to get direct support from Elegant Themes regarding this.

I am guessing the firs thing they will ask you to do is disable all of your plugins to see if the issue goes away when you do. If so, you can re-enable them one by one to isolate which plugin conflicts.